# Python/Bokeh - Plotting Data with Gaps on a Log Scale

Tags: python, bokeh

I am working with a dataset in Pandas - Bokeh that has several places where a value is `NaN`. When making a standard scatter plot, the plotting interface simply leaves out the rows that contain `NaN` values. However, when I change either axis to log scale, none of the points plot at all. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a known issue that is listed as a milestone for version 0.9.4. Check out this thread: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2162

I'm having a similar issue, so as a workaround I have split my ranges by nan values and plotted each set individually. This is based on Bokeh's [log scale example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#log-scale-axes) and [unutbu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605734/numpy-split-1d-array-of-chunks-separated-by-nans-into-a-list-of-the-chunks).

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import LogAxis, Range1d

def using_clump(a, b):
    return [a[s] for s in np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_invalid(b))]
def main():
    x = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, np.nan, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
    y = [10**xx for xx in x]
    output_file("log.html")

    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           y_axis_type="log", y_range=(10**-1, 10**4))

    xdata = using_clump(x, x)
    ydata = using_clump(y, x)
    for i in range(0, len(xdata)):
        p.line(xdata[i], ydata[i], line_width=2)
        p.circle(xdata[i], ydata[i], fill_color="white", size=8)

    show(p)
```

[image]