# The first and the last number between None's in a python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this

```
[None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, None, None , None , None, None, 
None, None, 169, 37, 9 ,7 ,23, None , None , 111, 24, 8 7 , 9, 12 , 74, None.......]
```

I need always first and the last value between the None's, the result should look like this

[8,2,169,23,111,74,...]

Does any one know how i can get these numbers back easily ?

Comment: Didn't you try anything first?

Comment: What should be the result for `[None, None,1, 2, 3, 4]`? `[4,5,6,7,None]`? `[8,None,9,None,10]`?

Comment: @Eric This is a good question, I had done some backtesting and my result was that this [8,None,9,None,10] will never happen there will always at least two numbers next to each other. The result of your question are [None, None,1, 2, 3, 4] => [1,4] , [4,5,6,7,None] => [4,7] , [8,1,None,9,2,None,10,2] => [8,1,9,2,10,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized way with `numpy`:

```
arr = np.asarray(arr)
# find all the nones - need the np.array to work around backwards-compatible misbehavior
is_none = arr == np.array(None)

# find which values are on an edge. Start and end get a free pass for being not none
is_edge = ~is_none
is_edge[1:-1] &= (is_none[2:] | is_none[:-2])

# use the boolean mask as an index
res = arr[is_edge]
```

`is_edge` could be calculated more verbosely but perhaps more clearly as:

```
is_edge = ~is_none & (
    np.pad(is_none[1:], (0,1), mode='constant', constant_values=True)
    |
    np.pad(is_none[:-1], (1,0), mode='constant', constant_values=True)
)
```

Comment: I'm getting a error if use the boolean as mask ( only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index). This is how fix it     newArr = np.where(~is_edge, 0, arr),   res =  newArr[newArr != 0]

Comment: @user3371372: see my update. You need an `arr = np.asarray(arr)` first

Answer (score 2):

A NumPy array that contains `None` and integers will be of type`object` anyway.
Seems like it it easier to use a list in the first place:

```
res = []
for x1, x2 in zip(L[:-1], L[1:]):
    if (x1 is not None and x2 is None):
        res.append(x1)
    elif (x1 is None and x2 is not None): 
        res.append(x2)
```

None `res` is:

```
[8, 2, 169, 23, 111, 74]
```

To avoid wrong results when the list does not start or end with `None`, limit the search into the part between the first and last `None`:

```
res = []
start = L.index(None)
end = len(L) - L[::-1].index(None)

for x1, x2 in zip(L[start:end-1], L[start+1:end]):
    if (x1 is not None and x2 is None):
        res.append(x1)
    elif (x1 is None and x2 is not None): 
        res.append(x2)
```

If you have a NumPy array with NaN instead of None:

```
a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 7, 2, np.nan,
              np.nan , np.nan , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 169, 37, 9,
              7 ,23, np.nan , np.nan , 111, 24, 8, 7 , 9, 12 , 74, np.nan])
```

You can do this in a vectorized way:

```
b = a[np.isnan(np.roll(a, 1)) | np.isnan(np.roll(a, -1))]
res = b[~np.isnan(b)]
```

Now `res` looks like this:

```
array([   8.,    2.,  169.,   23.,  111.,   74.])
```

Again, a version with limited
 search between first and last NaN:

```
indices = np.arange(len(a))[np.isnan(a)]
short = a[indices[0]:indices[-1]]
b = short[np.isnan(np.roll(short, 1)) | np.isnan(np.roll(short, -1))]
res = b[~np.isnan(b)]
```

Comment: Buggy with opening/trailing numbers e.g. [1, 2, None, 3, 4] -> [2, 3], whereas desired -> []

Comment: I like the vectorized way, very nice. Easy enough to `map` the `None`s to `np.nan`s.

Comment: @innisfree Added versions that fix this bug.

Comment: @MikeMüller Thanks for the code it's brilliant but had some problems plotting nan, this way i'm using none.

Comment: You can vectorize it with `None`s as well - see my answer. There is a performance penalty compared with using `nan`, but it ought to be faster than a pure-python solution

Answer (score 1):

Using the pandas package - thanks to innisfree for mentioning bug if series doesn't start/end with None:

```
import pandas
x=numpy.array([1,3,4,None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, None, None,7,8])
z = pandas.Series(numpy.append(numpy.insert(x,0,None),None))
res = z[z.shift(1).isnull() | z.shift(-1).isnull()].dropna()
```

Comment: Buggy with opening/trailing numbers e.g. [1, 2, None, 3, 4] -> [2, 3], whereas desired -> []

Comment: @innisfree: Nope, desired is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` - see the comments on the question

Answer (score 1):

Stealing a lot from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606271/5992438) you can do this:

Convert your `None`s to `nan`:

```
x = [None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, None, None , None , None, None, 
None, None, 169, 37, 9 ,7 ,23, None , None , 111, 24, 8 7 , 9, 12 , 74, None]

x = np.array(x,dtype=np.float)
```

and then:

```
x = np.vstack([a[s].take([0,-1]) for s in np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_invalid(x))]).flatten()
```

This divides your array into arrays that correspond to contiguous groups of non-`nan` values. Then it gets the first and last elements in these arrays using `.take([0,-1])`. Then it stacks these arrays into one array and flattens it.

```
print(repr(x))

array([   8.,    2.,  169.,   23.,  111.,   74.])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, None, None , None , None, None, 
None, None, 169, 37, 9 ,7 ,23, None , None , 111, 24, 8, 7 , 9, 12 , 74, None]

a.append(None)
[a[e] for e in range(len(a)-1) if a[e]!=None and (a[e-1]==None or a[e+1]==None)]
```

Output:

```
[8, 2, 169, 23, 111, 74]
```

Comment: I know this is not numpy but this code is nice, compact, and beautiful. Thanks @JCA

Comment: This throws an `IndexError` if `a[0] is None`

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would do it with regular Python lists. I don't have a specific answer with numpy arrays.

```
result = []
for ind, n in enumerate(lst):
    if n is not None and (lst[ind-1] is None or lst[ind+1] is None):
        result.append(n)
```

**Note:** This will give incorrect result if index `0` or `len - 1`(last element) is a number.

Comment: I think it may be because this raises an `IndexError` if the last item in the list is not `None`.

Comment: You could add `if n and (0 < ind < len(lst)-1) and ...` which should fix it. Otherwise quite a simple, elegant answer.

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer, but better because it uses `is`

Comment: @AndrewGuy The note I left actually meant for that issue, it is not hard to overcome, so I did not bother implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
ex = [None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, 
      None, None , None , None, None, None, None, 169, 37, 9 ,7 ,23,
      None , None , 111, 24, 87 , 9, 12 , 74, 
      None]

filt = [y for x, y, z in zip(ex, ex[1:], ex[2:]) 
        if y is not None and (x is None or z is None)]

# [8, 2, 169, 23, 111, 74]
```

This requires no external dependencies; however, making two extra copies for my zipped iterator could be costly if the list is particularly big. There are probably ways to overcome this with e.g. itertools.

Note that if your original list has leading or trailing numbers, the above could fail. Strip them first, e.g.

```
while ex[0] is not None:
    del ex[0]

while ex[-1] is not None:
    del ex[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of `zip` is that you can do this "triple iteration" kind of thing (loop through the list considering three items at a time):

```
result = []
for previous, item, next in zip(x[1:], x, np.hstack((None, x))):
    if item and None in (previous, next):
        result.append(item)
```

The other answers are also reasonable, this was an attempt at readability/understandability.

Comment: Buggy with opening/trailing numbers e.g. [1, 2, None, 3, 4] -> [2, 3], whereas desired -> []

Comment: @innisfree The OP didn't make it particularly clear what to do in the case you're talking about. Thankfully the question is targeted on a specific piece of data that has leading/trailing `None`s

Comment: It's clear - 'I need always first and the last value between the None's'. It doesn't say, I need any value that is adjacent to a None.

Comment: The op has clarified their intent, and they want `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as the output for that case

Comment: Mixing `np` and `zip` is kinda strange

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and it involves a function from another external package: [`iteration_utilities.split`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/split.html) but if you're operating on a `list` it will probably be relativly fast:

```
>>> lst = [None, None, None, None, None, 8, 7, 2, None, None , None , None, None, 
       None, None, 169, 37, 9 ,7 ,23, None , None , 111, 24, 8, 7 , 9, 12 , 74, None]

>>> from iteration_utilities import Iterable, is_None
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> Iterable(lst).split(is_None           # split by None
                ).filter(None             # remove empty lists
                ).map(itemgetter(0, -1)   # get the first and last element of each splited part
                ).flatten(                # flatten the result
                ).as_list()               # and convert it to a list
[8, 2, 169, 23, 111, 74]
```

Note that you can also do (something like) this in pure Python as well:

```
def first_last_between_None(iterable):
    last = None
    for item in iterable:
        # If we're in the None-part just proceed until we get a not None
        if last is None:
            if item is None:
                continue
            else:
                # Not None, reset last and yield the current value
                last = item
                yield item
        else:
            # If the next item is None we're at the end of the number-part
            # yield the last item.
            if item is None:
                yield last
            last = item
    if last is not None:
        yield last

>>> list(first_last_between_None(lst))
[8, 2, 169, 23, 111, 74]
```

If you want to discard the first and last values when it didn't start or end with `None` simply take the appropriate slice:

```
if lst[0] is not None:
    res = res[2:]
if lst[-1] is not None:
    res = res[:-2]
```

Comment: Buggy with opening/trailing numbers e.g. [1, 2, None, 3, 4], desired -> []

Comment: @innisfree Sorry if I input `[1,2,None,3,4]` it results in `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Why do you think it should be `[]`?

Comment: None of the numbers in the list [1, 2, None, 3, 4] lie between two None's.

Comment: @innisfree Given that the OP had a list which started and "ended" with `None` it didn't seem so important. I've included a solution for this in the answer. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @tom Why? It needs to discard two elements (first, last) of each block, because these aren't wrapped by Nones.

Comment: @tom I don't need to know! You can simply run the code and check if it's returning wrong result. It would be easier for me to understand what isn't working if you can given me an explicit input where it fails.